# Why don't we see an MMU on a high-end MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, processor

In the past, microcontrollers were fairly simple and had poor performance, making the idea of running a full OS on them not viable.

Today, there are multi-core MCUs running at over 500 MHz (e.g. Cortex-M7) but an MMU has still not been added.

Why is this?

Attempts to simulate MMU by using relocatable code exist but they are never real replacements.

Why haven't manufactures been interested in implementing a true single-chip computer?

Comment: They target applications and if the application is made for is not expected to run an OS that requires an MMU then it won't have one. Googling around, this is likely because it's expected for use in a real-time systems, and an RTOS does not use an MMU because it's thread based vs processed based (though I do not know what that actually means). https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/embedded-software/2019/09/16/do-you-need-a-memory-management-unit/

Comment: RTOS would use an MMU absolutely. The work arounds for lack of MMU riddle the RTOS landscape,

Comment: ARM Cortex-A MCUs exist. They have a MMU. Cortex-M is the "No-MMU" product line.

Comment: @JonathanS. Isn't the Cortex-A an application processor?

Comment: ARM has offered MMUs on their high end embedded processors for 20 years now, so this question doesn't make sense. Maybe you wanted to ask why they offer an option to not have an MMU?

Comment: An application processor is just a microcontroller with a MMU (which can therefore run Linux, for example). It's just nomenclature.

Comment: Which RTOS are you trying to implement?

Comment: The A series isn't an MCU. MCU contain everything they need to run as a stand alone chip. Processors don't normally include SRAM which is accessible with normal load/store instructions.

Comment: Most of it is marketing terminology anyway.

Comment: It's not, MCU are designed to run as a single chip, microprocessors are not. None of the A series are MCU.

Comment: You are confusing a lot of unrelated things. Before rebranding it was common to see an MMU option on ARM's MCUs, but now arm marketing is more coherent which is what you're apparently reading. ARM9TDMI and ARM9E were available with MMUs which could be disabled if you didn't want to use them. Internal memory mapped SRAM was (and still is) often on all kinds of ARM processors. Similarly both MCUs and application processors are available as SoCs. Did any of that answer your question?

Comment: I don't think the distinctions you are making are as widely recognized and used as you think. To me, perhaps out of ignorance, the terms "microprocessor" "microcontroller" and "MCU" are largely interchangeable. Although I guess I seldom say "microprocessor," I guess.

Comment: @JonathanS. Seems like an answer: when a microcontroller has an MMU, it's no longer "micro"

Comment: @FourierFlux - [here is an example of a Cortex-A5 device](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/legacy-mpu-mcus/vfxxx-controller/vfxxx-f-series/arm-cortex-a5-plus-cortex-m4-mpus-1-5-mb-sram-lcd-security-ethernet-l2-switch:VF6xx) which clearly is an MCU. It has up to 1.5MB of embedded SRAM and all the peripherals you'd expect in an MCU and is perfectly capable of running 'stand-alone'.

Comment: @mkeith, **a CPU** is a processor capable of executing instructions and programs. **A microprocessor** is a CPU plus external bus interface circuitry (BIU etc), all on a single IC. To implement a computing device, a microprocessor requires external ICs such as memories and I/O devices. **A microcontroller** is a CPU, bus interfacing, memories and I/O devices all on a single IC. To implement a computing device, it doesn't require external ICs. **MCU** stands for **M**icro**c**ontroller **U**nit, a term dating back to (or coined for) 1976 and Intel's MCS-48 family, which is where I first saw it.

Answer (score 8):

A microcontroller with an MMU is simply called an "application processor", it's not a MCU anymore. This is just a nomenclature thing - modern microcontrollers and application processors are identical apart from the inclusion of an MMU and possibly a memory interface.

ARM's Cortex-M product line is defined as an ARM core *without an MMU* (hence "M" for "microcontroller"). If you want an MMU you have to get a Cortex-A, which is ARM *with* an MMU ("A" for "application processor").

Manufacturers have of course been very interested in implementing "true single chip computers", called a "System on Chip" (SoC). You can get them in almost any configuration imaginable. Most of them use external DRAM because if you want to run any kind of "heavier" operating system that needs an MMU, you'll also need more RAM. They often have at least some internal SRAM too, though.

The M1 chip found in Apple's newest computers is actually a fully integrated System on Chip. As far as I know, even the DRAM and Flash are built right into it. The Raspberry Pi's main chip is also a SoC which includes the system's DRAM and is capable of running with barely any external components. Single chip computers are in widespread use.